# Mysql, coding database to UTF-8

Tags: mysql, oracle, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have strange problem, meaning:

in my company we have 2 kinds of databases 1 oracle and 1 mysql and 1 remote in hosting.
when ERP which is on oracle codding is set to utf-8 is making update or insert to remote mysql db everything is ok all chars like `ńłóść` are coded correctly, but doing the same update to my local mysql db chars like `ńłóść` are replaced by `?`. I tried to

change coding from `utf8_general_ci` to `utf8_unicode_ci` didn't work,

change engine from `InnoDB` to `MylSam` didn't work

varsion of my local MySQL is `5.6.12`

version of my remote MYSQL is `5`

but i don't think there is problem, i use wamp 2.4

Can i check in what encoding query is ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use `utf8mb4`. Search for it on Stack Overflow, or see [***How to support full Unicode in MySQL databases***](http://mths.be/utf8mb4).